# The meaning of "[~,P]" in the function randperm

Tags: matlab, permutation

I'm bit of a noobie in Matlab and so I typed 'edit randperm' in my matlab script and I did not understood the meaning of [~,P] in the code '[~,P]=sort(rand(1,n))' -- which is the code that showed up to me. Can anyone help me? From the little of what I've understood [~,P] seems to turn the numbers into intergers (with range of 1 til n). But the way it is assigned in the code seems very strange. And I do want to know what is the exact purpose of '~' and 'P' in the code.

(I also would be glad if anyone had tips on how to properly write this question on stackoverflow. I'm also new here)

Answer (score 1):

This uses the following form of the `sort()` function:

```
[B,IX] = sort(A,...)
```

documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

The tilde in

```
[~,P]=sort(...)
```

means that the first return value should be discarded (and the second return value should be assigned to `P`).

The overall effect of `[~,P]=sort(rand(1,n))` is to assign to `P` a random permutation of the numbers from `1` to `n`.